# What data is lost when migrating an ESXi host between vCenter servers?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I am getting ready to remove some ESXi machines from an older vCenter inventory and add them to a newer one. I'm trying to create a list of all data that will not make the migration. Reading through VMware docs, I have already found that historical performance data, distributed virtual switch configs, resource pools, and VM folder structures do not move with the host. Is this information correct? Are there other pieces that will be lost during the move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loose everything that lives in the vCenter- you already mentioned historical performance data, distributed virtual switch configs and VM folder structures. I'm not sure about resource pools... I think you will loose them if they are defined in a cluster (vCenter level!) but it's possible that they will survive for stand-alone hosts.

HA restart priorities, DRS rules, storage policies and permissions (in vCenter, not permissions defined on the host directly) shouldn't move with the host, either.